# mongoose returns empty array on querying mongolab database/

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mlab

I am new to mongodb and mongoose , I am trying to follow a book to learn it. I have an existing database on mongolab named "firstdatabase" which has a collection named "parking_info" and this is one record from that collection:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "559c152fa439a961c357f931"
    },
    "POST_ID": "354-20160",
    "MS_ID": "-",
    "MS_SPACEID": 0,
    "CAP_COLOR": "Grey",
    "METER_TYPE": "SS",
    "SMART_METE": "Y",
    "ACTIVESENS": "N",
    "JURISDICTI": "SFMTA",
    "ON_OFF_STR": "ON",
    "OSP_ID": 0,
    "STREET_NUM": 2016,
    "STREETNAME": "CHESTNUT ST",
    "STREET_SEG": 3977000,
    "RATEAREA": "Area 5",
    "SFPARKAREA": "Marina",
    "LOCATION": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            37.8007983983,
            -122.4368696024
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to use this database in a nodejs application using mongoose. This is my directory structure :

```
>models
-->parking.js
>views
-->parkings.handlebars
>credentials.ja
>app.js
```

in parking.js  --> I am creating the schema.

```
// mongoose scehma
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var parkingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "POST_ID": String,
    "MS_ID": String,
    "MS_SPACEID": Number,
    "CAP_COLOR": String,
    "METER_TYPE": String,
    "SMART_METE": String,
    "ACTIVESENS": String,
    "JURISDICTI": String,
    "ON_OFF_STR": String,
    "OSP_ID": Number,
    "STREET_NUM": Number,
    "STREETNAME": String,
    "STREET_SEG": Number,
    "RATEAREA": String,
    "SFPARKAREA": String,
    "LOCATION": {
        "type": String,
        "coordinates": [Number]
    }
});

var Parking = mongoose.model('parking_info', parkingSchema);
module.exports = Parking;
```

And in my app.js I have :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Parking = require('./models/parking');

var opts = {
    server: {
        socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1 }
    }
};
switch(app.get('env')){
    case 'development':
        mongoose.connect(credentials.mongo.development.connectionString, opts);
        console.log('connected..to db');
        break;
    case 'production':
        mongoose.connect(credentials.mongo.production.connectionString, opts);
        break;
    default:
        throw new Error('Unknown execution environment: ' + app.get('env'));
}


app.get("/parkings", function(req, res){
    Parking.find(function(err, parkings){
        if(err){
            console.log('error..');
            return handleError(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('returning parkings..');
            res.render( "parkings", parkings);
        }

    });

});
```

and I am trying to show the data in parkings.handlebars

```
<h1>Parkings</h1>
{{#each parkings}}
    <div class="parking">
        <h3>{{STREETNAME}}</h3>

    </div>
{{/each}}
```

But my Parking.find returns an empty array , could someone help me understanding where I am going wrong.? I am following a book Web Development with Node and Express by Ethan Brown

Comment: try adding one more parameter to your `.find()` method call, an object with parameters for the search to use - and then moving your callback function as a second parameter to `.find()`. After try adding  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Answer (score 7):

Another way to solve your problem is to define explicitly the collection name in your model, i.e. `var Parking = mongoose.model('parking_info', parkingSchema, 'parking_info');`. Mongoose conventions are used if no collection name is specified.

See : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model

> Parameters:
>
> - name  model name
> - [schema]
> - [collection]  name (optional, induced from model name)
> - [skipInit]  whether to skip initialization (defaults to false)

*"When no collection argument is passed, Mongoose produces a collection name by passing the model name to the utils.toCollectionName method. This method pluralizes the name. If you don't like this behavior, either pass a collection name or set your schemas collection name option."*

Answer (score 0):

You need an object as the first argument to your Model's `.find()` method call. Since you want everything in the collection you may pass in an empty object.

```
app.get("/parkings", function(req, res){
    Parking.find({}, function(err, parkings){
        if(err){
            console.log('error..');
            return handleError(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('returning parkings..');
            res.render( "parkings", { parkings: parkings });
        }

    });

});
```

Reference: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: @Sgni .. thanks for the reply.. I did that but still the response is same.

Comment: @swatisaoji updated my comment, I changed the `res.render`'s options. I set a new object literal and set the key of `parkings` to the value of `parkings` that's the data coming from the mongoose query.

Comment: @Sgni its the same , actually the data coming from query is empty array. I checked using a debugger.

Comment: @swatisaoji Since I can't see the value of  `credentials.mongo.development.connectionString`, you've double-checked that your db connection is connecting to the right db `firstdatabase`?

Comment: @Sgnl You don't NEED to pass in anything for the conditions parameter. Mongoose will check to see if the first argument is a function, if so it'll set the conditions equal to an empty object.  https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/query.js#L1072

Comment: Hey @Sgni i got the array now , the thing is my collection is named parking_info and during debugging i saw the collection name as parking_infos --> so i changed my collection name to parking_infos and it worked.. But I really have no idea about the cocept behind.. has to do something with naming conventions or so..

Comment: ah yes! the ORM (is this case mongoose), like many other ORMs will pluralize the collection name. Like you said it's a naming convention and it's a pretty standard convention.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do this?

```
<h1>Parkings</h1>
{{#each parkings}}
    <div class="parking">
        <h3>{{_doc.STREETNAME}}</h3>

    </div>
{{/each}}
```

After you change this

```
res.render( "parkings", parkings);
```

To

```
res.render( "parkings", { parkings: parkings });
```

Comment: it is just the same. and when i use res.send({ parkings: parkings });  intead of rendering a view.. I get {"parkings":[]} actually the  parkings is empty array.

Comment: @swatisaoji EDIT: Checked your other comment on the other answer.. You've debugged it and found that it actually returns an empty array? OR are you just assuming so based on the empty HTML?

Comment: --> its was an empty array . Please check my comment in other answer --> its working now, Thanks for the time and help . I learnt a lot from the answers and discussion.

Answer (score -1):

**I am compiling the comments that are the solution to my question:**

The issue was:  my collection is named parking_info and during debugging i saw the collection name as parking_infos --> so i changed my collection name to parking_infos and it worked.

Sgni : -> the ORM (is this case mongoose), like many other ORMs will pluralize the collection name.

So just as convention-> collections should have plural names